# Convergence of series of linear operators in Banach space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $A\in L(X,X)$. Show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!} $$
converges in $L(X,X)$. Find an upper bound to the norm of sum.

If a series converges absolutely, then it converges. I could say that
$$\frac{1}{k!}\|A^k\|\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}0 $$ if $A$ was bounded, is it, though? At any rate, that alone is not enough to show convergence. I'm not sure how I should approach this, the lecture notes seemingly don't give any relevant info on how to show such convergence.

Comment: Isn't $L(X,X)$ the space of bounded linear maps $X \to X$? If so, then $$\left| \sum_k \frac{A^k}{k!} \right| \le \sum_k\frac{|A^k|}{k!} \le \sum_k\frac{|A|^k}{k!} = e^{|A|} < \infty$$

Comment: OH?? I thought it was just a space of linear maps, must revisit the notes.

Comment: It may be that $L(X,X)$ denotes the space of all linear maps. But in that case, there is no standard notion of "convergence in $L(X,X)$", because it is not endowed with a standard topology. No topology, no convergence.

Comment: I have never seen "L" denote anything but continuous linear maps. However, now that you mention it, I would be curious to know for which spaces X there exists a topology on the set of all (continuous and discontinuous) linear operators acting on X which would turn it into a tvs (or, better yet, a norm to turn it into a normed space).